# Enthernet cable not detected by Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

Enthernet cable not detected by Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but it is being detected by Windows 8 and the internet is also not working in the terminal (even through the WiFi). please help !!!

"ifconfig -a" gives-

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:9e:01:3a:d4:23  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:5370 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5370 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:561875 (561.8 KB)  TX bytes:561875 (561.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:16:54:36:01:4b  
      inet addr:192.168.9.112  Bcast:192.168.9.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::fa16:54ff:fe36:14b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:77313 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:60445 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:76206087 (76.2 MB)  TX bytes:9180341 (9.1 MB)
```

"lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net' -A2" gives-

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3801]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4262]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

"ifconfig ; ping -c 1 192.168.9.1; ping -c 1 google.com" gives-

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:9e:01:3a:d4:23  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:855 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:855 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:90882 (90.8 KB)  TX bytes:90882 (90.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:16:54:36:01:4b  
      inet addr:192.168.9.112  Bcast:192.168.9.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::fa16:54ff:fe36:14b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3904 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3559 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3642123 (3.6 MB)  TX bytes:535618 (535.6 KB)

PING 192.168.9.1 (192.168.9.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.9.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=2.84 ms

--- 192.168.9.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.842/2.842/2.842/0.000 ms
PING google.com (216.58.208.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from par10s21-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.208.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=263 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 263.058/263.058/263.058/0.000 ms
```

"route -n" gives-

```
    Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.9.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.9.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

"sudo lshw -C network" gives-

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 10
   serial: 08:9e:01:3a:d4:23
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:62 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:b5504000-b5504fff memory:b5500000-b5503fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 73
   serial: f8:16:54:36:01:4b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 ip=192.168.9.112 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:64 memory:b5400000-b5401fff
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net' -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Does Wi-Fi work?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes the WiFi works and please check the edited question....

Comment: What do you mean that internet does not work in terminal. Please add output of `route -n`.

Comment: @Pilot6 output for route -n added in the question. please check !!

Comment: Looks OK. Check the updated answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 doesn't work...

Comment: Internet works in terminal very well.

Comment: Have you tried different ethernet cable ? Are there any messages related to eth0 in logs such as dmesg, kern.log, syslog ?

Answer (score 0):

First you can fix your wireless connection by running in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

and reboot.

You seem to be behind a proxy. You will need to add it to your configuration.

Run `gedit ~/.bashrc` and add at the bottom of the file

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport
export http_proxy
```

Replace it with your real username, password, address and port.

Then if your wireless network starts working, you can install another driver for your Ethernet adapter by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

that should help for rev. 10.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26932/discussion-on-answer-by-pilot6-enthernet-cable-not-detected-by-ubuntu-14-04-lts).